# My intent does not launch desired activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I trrigger and intent as follows:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassname(packagename, activity path for my activity say 'xyz');
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

for my activity(xyz) i have exported="true" in its manifest file.

but this intent is not launching the desired activity(xyz), it only displays my activity's heading on a new window and then it shows Settins activity.

I am not sure where the problem might be.
Both my activities are in different packages.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh finaly i got fix for this..
There was some mislink which was creating the problem.
So i added meta-data in the AndroidManifest file for the activity which i was intending to launch via the intent.

Something like this:-

```
<activity android:name="abc$xyz"
    <meta-data android:name="com.vivek.abc.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
        android:value="com.vivek.abc.xyz" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.vivek.abc.PARENT_FRAGMENT_CLASS"
        android:value="the parent activity name" />
</activity>
```

And this worked perfectly for me.

Thank u all who tried to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Activity One:

```
Intent i = new Intent(One.this, Two.class);
//i.putExtra("result", data); //optional if you want pass some data
startActivity(i);
```

---

```
//optional to get data:
```

Activity Two:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = "";
if (intent.hasExtra("result")) {
   text = intent.getStringExtra("result");
} else {
    // no extras for result available.
}
```

Comment: Make sure that intent uses hasExtra() before using getStringExtra else it will cause a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold you are right. You can edit this answer if you wish.

Comment: thanks for ur help...but it didnot work......my desired activity only shows up for a fraction of seconds and then some other activity appeaars

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

`Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActicity.this, TargetActivity.class);`

then set your desired flags and call `startActivity();`

Comment: i have my desired activity in a different package , so i thought i must call it as intent.setClassName()....but its not opening the desired activity...it only flashes a blanck activity with its title as my desired activity and then it all vanished and opens Settings

Comment: do i need any permissions in android manifest to let my desired activity to be called from any other class outside its package?

Comment: No, you should include the package in your current activity though.

Answer (score 0):

With your flags setupted it's

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.getClass(), xyz.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Take care that you use addFlags instead of setFlags since setFlags will overrite all existing flags.